# Homeomorphism from equivalence classes to unit ball

Tags: general-topology

Say we have $X = I \times I \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, with $I = [0,1]$. Let's define an equivalence relation:

$(x,y) \sim (x',y')$ if one of the following holds

$\bullet \ (x,y) = (x',y') $

$\bullet \ x=x'=0 $

$\bullet \ x=x' \text{ and } \{y,y'\} = \{0,1\}  $

I have to show that $X/\sim$ with its quotient topology is homeomorphic to the ball $B^2$. How am I supposed to do that? How can I work towards such a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following map $f:I^2\to B^2$:
$$f(x,y) = (x\cos(2\pi y), x\sin (2\pi y)).$$

We can see that $f(x,y)=f(x',y')$ iff $x\sim y$, so it defines a continuous map $\tilde{f}:(I^2/\sim) \to B^2$. Moreover, you can also show that $f$ is onto (so does $\tilde{f}$.)

Now apply the following well-known theorem: if $g:A\to B$ is a bijective continuous function, and if $A$ is compact and $B$ is Hausdorff, then $g$ is a homeomorphism. Since $I^2$ is compact, so does $I^2/\sim$. Moreover, $B^2$ is Hausdorff. Hence $\tilde{f}$ is a homeomorphism.